# Easy explanation why electron emits photon when accelerated in $E$-field, but not in $B$-field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics

I know that when an electron gets accelerated (changes direction) in an electric field it emits a photon. An ad-hoc way of explaining this is, that the acceleration of the electron causes a ripple in the electromagnetic field and this ripple is the wave package of the photon.

Alright, but is there a simple, intuitive explanation why the same (electron emitting a photon) doesn't happen when the electron gets accelerated in a magnetic field? Isn't the magnetic field a component of the electromagnetic radiation? And further thinking - ss there some analogous particle, some kind of a particle with a magnetic field, that when accelerated in a magnetic field also emits photons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrons accelerating in a magnetic field *do* emit electromagnetic radiation. It is known as [synchrotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation) or curvature radiation.

Comment: Thanks! And what about particles with a magnetic field, do they also emit photons when accelerated in E- or B-field?